# Unable to get Inkwell splash effect

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I'm unable to get the splash effect for the custom button that I have created. I'm not sure, what's missing.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final double buttonHeight;
  final double buttonWidth;
  final Color backgroundColor;
  final Color textColor;
  final VoidCallback onClick;

  const CustomButton({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
    required this.buttonHeight,
    required this.buttonWidth,
    required this.backgroundColor,
    required this.textColor,
    required this.onClick,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        color: Color(0xFFFFC107),
      ),
      child: Material(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        child: InkWell(
          child: Container(
            height: buttonHeight,
            width: buttonWidth,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text(
              title,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Please find below my environment details for your kind reference:

```
Flutter 2.2.1 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 02c026b03c (2 weeks ago) • 2021-05-27 12:24:44 -0700
Engine • revision 0fdb562ac8
Tools • Dart 2.13.1
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to wrap your main container in InkWell instead of the child Container

Comment: InkWell uses Material, Use Material-> Ink -> InkWell, this might help! if not try rearranging these. upvote if it helped ! @xpetta